# how to troubleshoot aborted connection mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, connection, database-connection

I keep getting this in my mysql error log.

```
5 [Note] Aborted connection 5 to db: 'dbname' user: 'dbuser' host: 'localhost' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

Combed trough the php code and made sure that am calling mysqli->close on the db resource when my script is about to finish.

My project stack: apache2.4 with php-fpm7.2 and mysql 5.7.25 on ubuntu 18.10.

Is there any way i can get more insight into this issue?

Just checked firewall but it is Inactive

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

I found the issue for this. I was not clearing all results before closing the db connection so i just clear all results explicitly using php then i make the db->close. The log lines dissapeared from /var/log/mysql/error.log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue for this. I was not clearing all results before closing the db connection so i just clear all results explicitly using php then i make the db->close. The log lines dissapeared from /var/log/mysql/error.log.

Answer (score -2):

It may be firewall problem. Disable the firewall and try.

Comment: You can also try 127.0.0.1 in place of localhost.

Comment: If you can create new user for the db and use created new credentials for login

Comment: check mysql configuration file- my.cnf file and see what it contains in "bind-address" place

Comment: it is set to 127.0.0.1